# How to display text in corner of Bing Map?

Tags: javascript, css, bing-maps

I am trying to display text on top of bing map on right side corner.

It would be great if it's responsive. If size change that text still need to be display in corner.

I am using Javascript Bing API v=7

Comment: Your question is not directly linked to Bing Maps but it is rather a CSS question. In Bing Maps API, there no default panel or control to do this but you can easily add your own HTML content and handle it with appropriate CSS.

Comment: @NicolasBoonaert when did i even mention this directly to Bing Maps. Reason i mentions Bing Map because that's what i am using. I don't want whoever answer this question use Google or MapQuest map.

Comment: The tag used can be misleading for people since it is, once again, not specific to Bing Maps AJAX control at all but rather a CSS issue. CSS should be added as a tag and Bing Maps should be removed as just 2 div elements that need to be well positioned. That's it :)

Comment: @NicolasBoonaert This question is for related to Bing Map. I don't want to display text on top of any div. I also agree that i need to add css tag here. I don't see any reason why did you vote down this question? I added css tag.

Comment: There you go, I fixed the downvote now. Nevermind it's still really a CSS issue rather than a Bing maps specific, but if Ricky's answer helped you, then it's is great and I'm glad your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to float the text over top the map. This is just simple HTML/CSS. Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function GetMap()
    {   
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), { 
            credentials: "YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY"
        });
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    html, body{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    .mapStyle{
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    .myTextOverlay{
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 40px;
        right:10px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
    <div class="mapStyle">
        <div id='myMap' class="mapStyle"></div>
        <div class="myTextOverlay">My custom Text</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```